# Solidity delegatecall fails with "function selector was not recognized" when using enum

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have the following function

```
   enum OptionType {Invalid, Put, Call}

   function create(
    uint256 period,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 strike,
    OptionType optionType
) {
    ....
}
```

When I try to delegatecall this function from another contract using this

```
address(contractAddress).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)",1,1,1,1));
```

I get the error

**function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function**

Comment: `create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)` produces correct signature `0x80478ad1` (same as when you're calling the function directly). I was not able to reproduce your issue, Solidity 0.8 gives me `Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)" to bytes4 requested.` for the `encodeWithSelector()`. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `contractAddress` is valid and your using the right version of solidity

this seemed to work fine when externally calling a function with an enum

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
       enum OptionType {Invalid, Put, Call}

    function create(
        uint256 period,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 strike,
        OptionType optionType
    ) public returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
    function delegatCallTest() public view returns(bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(this).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)",1,1,1,1));
        require(success);
        return data;
    }
}
```